# Find one string and get related values

Tags: php, arrays, codeigniter, strpos

I have several strings, how can I search the first value and get other values from it?

`print_r` or `?`:

```
Array( [0] => Title,11,11 [1] => Would,22,22 [2] => Post,55,55 [3] => Ask,66,66 )
```

like:

If send for this array value `Title` and getting  values `Title,11,11`
Or send `Would` getting  values `Would,22,22`
Or send `Post` getting  values `Post,55,55`
Or send `Ask` getting  values `Ask,66,66`

How can do it?

Answer (score 1):

Loop over the array with [foreach](http://nz.php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php) and match the value with [strpos](http://nz.php.net/manual/en/function.strpos.php).

Answer (score 1):

suppose:

```
$arr = Array( [0] => Title,11,11 [1] => Would,22,22 [2] => Post,55,55 [3] => Ask,66,66 )
$string = 'Would';
```

then

```
//Call the function with the search value in $string and the actual array
$required_arr[$string] = search_my_array($string, $arr);

function($str , $array)
{
    //Trace the complete array
    for($i = 0; $i<count($array); $i++)
    {  
        //Break the array using explode function based on ','
        $arr_values[$i] = explode(',',$array[i])
        if($str == $arr_values[$i][0]) // Match the First String with the required string
        {
            //On match return the array with the values contained in it
            return array($arr_values[$i][1], $arr_values[$i][2]);
        }
    }
}
```

Now

```
$required_arr['Would']    // will hold Array([0] => 22 [1] => 22)
```

Answer (score 1):

Write a function to search the array. This should work well enough

```
<?php
  // test array
  $arr = array('Title,11,11','Would,22,22','Post,55,55','Ask,66,66');
  // define search function that you pass an array and a search string to
  function search($needle,$haystack){
    // loop over each passed in array element
    foreach($haystack as $v){
      // if there is a match at the first position
      if(strpos($v,$needle) === 0)
        // return the current array element
        return $v;
    }
    // otherwise retur false if not found
    return false;
  }
  // test the function
  echo search("Would",$arr);
?>
```

Comment: This function may return Boolean FALSE, but may also return a non-Boolean value which evaluates to FALSE, such as 0 or "". Please read the section on Booleans for more information. Use the === operator for testing the return value of this function.Source: http://php.net/strpos ???

Comment: It was @greg0ire who added the extra `=` - I guess because he did not understand my code. I am not trying to detect if there is a match or not with boolean value, but to detect if the match is at position 0. I think `==` is the correct  one to use here right?

Comment: Are you aware that 0 == false, but 0 !== false ? This was in my comment for the modification. Since strpos() might return false, the additional = is important, right?

Comment: @Billy Moon : Your test will pass if the needle is not found.

Comment: @greg0ire : of course you are right - I got very confused with it all for some reason. I actually had the needle and haystack the wrong way round in the `strpos` function too. Can you check this is all correct for me now. Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

are the indices important ? why not ..

```
$arr = array(
  'Title' => array(11, 11),
  'Would' => array(22, 22),
  'Post' => array(55, 55),
  'Ask' => array(66,66)
);

$send = "Title";     // for example
$result = $arr[$send];
```

Comment: If `$arr` was this: `Array( [0] => Title,11,11 [1] => Would,22,22 [2] => Post,55,55 [3] => Ask,66,66 )` how is it?

Comment: @Scott Evernden : nice try ^^

Answer (score 0):

How about using something like, so you don't loop trough entire array:

```
$array = array( "Title,11,11", "Would,22,22", "Post,55,55", "Ask,66,66" );
$key = my_array_search('Would', $array);
$getvalues = explode(",", $array[$key]);

function my_array_search($needle = null, $haystack_array = null, $skip = 0)
{
    if($needle == null || $haystack_array == null)
        die('$needle and $haystack_array are mandatory for function my_array_search()');
    foreach($haystack_array as $key => $eval)
    {
        if($skip != 0)$eval = substr($eval, $skip);
        if(stristr($eval, $needle) !== false) return $key;
    }
    return false;
}
```